# How to move a column of a table vertically in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabular

I have a bootstrap table like below:

[image]

I want the picture on the bottom.I know if I place the things on a different row it is possible but for my context it's not what I want. So basically I want the column which contains the **td2** table will be below the **td** columns. Can I achieve this.

Comment: When adding tags you need to read the description of the tags.  The design tag is not for this type of question.  Other people use these tags to track and follow certain subjects on SO.

Answer (score 0):

No. you can't do this with a table, the "table"-element has been made especially to avoid situations like this.

You could solve this with adding rows, as you suggested yourself, or by using other elements like `div` and, if you really want, some `float` left or right.

Don't forget that you can use the `colspan` attribute if you use new rows, and give it a special class, so you can easily get to that data with jquery.

On another note: pro drawing.

Comment: Actually I have data dependency on the table row, so don't able to do what you have suggested.So I have to do what I want within the table row itself.So helpless.@Jordumus